# Install Aptitude package on Raspberry Pi 3 with Android Things

Tags: raspberry-pi3, android-things

I've installed Android Things on my Raspberry Pi 3.

When I'm on the shell of my RPi3,

I note that there are not all commands of Linux, especially :

sudo
apt-get

Here is my OS :

```
1|rpi3:/ # uname -a
Linux localhost 4.4.19-v7+ #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Aug 18 02:59:59 UTC 2017 armv7l
```

Can we install these commands ?

Comment: _"I note that there are not all commands of Linux, especially `sudo apt-get`"_. What makes you think `Android Things` must be a `Linux`-like OS? Do you have an imagination what a "regular" `Android`'s `/system/bin` directory look like?

Comment: quick answer: **no**; but why do you want those tools?

Comment: There are lot of "Permission denied" on Android Things, I wished change configuration, I try to connect several component, but I will be limited with UARTs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Things is an operating system based on Linux, with the same underlying kernel. However, it does not necessarily support every tool that is part of desktop Linux operating systems.

Some tools like `apt-get` are only on a few Linux variants. Macs, which use the same Linux kernel, do not have `apt-get` installed either.

Some binary files may run on Android, and many may not. Software that use certain types of drivers may not be supported due to changes in permission models and hardware configurations.

On the Raspberry Pi, it may have a traditional desktop interface in Raspbian. However, when running Android Things many of the traditional Linux components may not run, instead being replaced by tools that may make more sense for Android like the Package Manager and Activity Manager.

Comment: Essentially correct, but Macs are based on the Unix kernel. RedHat would be a better example of a Linux distro that doesn't use apt-get